# Using between mysql function ignoring year

Tags: mysql, date, between

Ok, I have the following **Users** table:

```
id |  name  |  birthday 

1  |  nam1  |  1980-06-29  
2  |  nam2  |  1997-07-08  
3  |  nam3  |  1997-07-20
```

> Assuming that today is 2012-06-29

How can I get the users who will celebrate your birthdays in the next 15 days? I have tried with this:

```
select * from users where birthday between '%-06-29' and '%-07-14';
```

but looks like is not a valid query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the safest way is to compare their age in 15 days with their age today:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Users
WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 15 DAY)
     > TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURRENT_DATE)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62eeb/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

you should try operating on a substring of "birthday" so you can "cut" the year out of the field

Comment: Well, I have tried to avoid this option because I think that it forces MySQL to convert the column into a CHAR before performing the comparison and alter my performance.. or not? :s

Comment: you should be able to cast the values if anything using a Cast(Substring()), it may be redundant but in theory you could just convert both month and day to integers and operate that way