# How can I find upcoming birthday in ending of december month?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

```
select *
from date
where DATE_FORMAT(sdate,'%m-%d') between
   DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d') and
   DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%m-%d')
```

This code is run perfectly but when current date is 29th december and interval days are 7 so it will not show any output. But I also want birthdays between 29th December to 4th January.
At that time this code is not perfect for my requirement.

Comment: So, basically, you're looking for a time interval of 7 days, starting from 25th of december and ending on 31st(including)?

Comment: @AndreiP. Where on earth did you get the 25th from?

Comment: if you need dates in interval of time "ignoring" the year, you should take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265610/using-between-mysql-function-ignoring-year

Comment: Starting from the 29th of December and ending on 4 January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the year like that :

```
SELECT *
FROM dates
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sDATE,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN
   DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
   DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

If `sdate` is the user subscription date and you want to wish him his birthday, add 1 year to the `sdate` :

```
SELECT *
FROM dates
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(sdate,INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN
   DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
   DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

If you want to get all anniversaries dates, you can do that. (sorry for the dirtiness, I just want to know if it's the resut you expect) :

```
SELECT * FROM dates WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sdate,'%m-%d') IN (
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY),'%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAY),'%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 4 DAY),'%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY),'%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 6 DAY),'%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%m-%d'))
```

Here is some PHP code to generate the query with the interval you want:

```
    $interval = 10;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dates WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sdate,'%m-%d') IN (DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d')";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $interval; $i++) {
        $query .= ", DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL $i DAY),'%m-%d')";
    }
    $query .= ");";
```

Comment: Yes It is working but basically birthday's Year is not current year. It is Past year.  So in my point of view we don't have to compare with year.

Comment: We have to ignore year in this case.

Comment: What do you want to do ? What is `sdate` ? Is it the subscription date of your user ?

Comment: I edited my code if you want to wish your user's subscription birthday.

Comment: sdate is starting date.  But I considered it as Birth-date.

Comment: And do you want to get the one year anniversary only or all anniversaries ?

Comment: I have birth dates which starts from 1991-12-29 to 1992-01-04. So on 29 december If I add Interval 7 days so I should have output of all date between 1991-12-29 to 1992-01-04. But current year is 2014 so we have to ignore year only focus on motnhs and days.

Comment: Ok, did you try the solution below proposed by @manix ? I think it's what you need.

Comment: It is working but problem is arise at when month is december. 29 december and I add interval days 7, It will not give output of january dates. This code is only valid till 31st december.

Comment: I just edited my answer with a new proposal. Can you try it :) ?

Comment: Yes it is work. But I want 7 days then I have to type 7 time, 10 time for 10 days. Is there any shortcode for this ?

Comment: Thank you sir, Is there any short code for your suggested query?

Comment: You can generate the query with some php loop. I'll edit my code if you want with an example.

Comment: I just edited my answer with the query generated in PHP. Can you try it ?

Comment: You're welcome. I'd like if you would accept my answer and voted for if it's the result you were expeccting ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to search for birthdays is to subtract the day of the year from the dates.  This eliminates the problems at the end of the year:

```
select *
from date
where DATE_FORMAT(sdate - interval dayofyear(sdate) day, '%m-%d')
          between DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - interval dayofyear(sdate) day, '%m-%d') and
                  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - interval dayofyear(sdate) day + INTERVAL 7 DAY, '%m-%d');
```

Comment: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'

Answer (score 0):

Or compare their age in 7 days with their age today:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dates
WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sdate, CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
     > TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, sdate, CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(CONCAT(CASE WHEN (DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%c-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%c-%d')) THEN YEAR(CURDATE()) ELSE YEAR(CURDATE())+1 END,DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '-%c-%d'))  between CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
```

The above query snippet will work irrespective of whether it's a leap year or if the 90 day interval takes you to the next year.